# terraform get list variable to resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

```
variable "iam_action" {
  type    = "list"
  default = ["ec2.amazonaws.com","ecs.amazonaws.com"]
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "s3_role" {
  name               = "abcd"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [ "${var.iam_action}"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow,
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Error:

```
At column 1, line 1: output of an HIL expression must be a string, or a single list (argument 2 is TypeList) in:
```

I tried join function but i need output to be a list `["a","b","c"]` join function gives output like `["a,b,c"]`

Answer (score 5):

I fix it with `jsonencode` by `template_file`

First create below json file

```
$ cat s3_policy.json

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ${iam_action}
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Update the tf file

```
variable "iam_action" {
  type    = "list"
  default = ["ec2.amazonaws.com", "ecs.amazonaws.com"]
}

data "template_file" "s3_role" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/s3_policy.json")}"

  vars {
    iam_action = "${jsonencode(var.iam_action)}"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "s3_role" {
  name = "abcd"

  assume_role_policy = "${data.template_file.s3_role.rendered}"
}
```

run `template plan`

```
  + aws_iam_role.s3_role
      arn:                   "<computed>"
      assume_role_policy:    "{\n  \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\n  \"Statement\": [\n    {\n      \"Action\": \"sts:AssumeRole\",\n      \"Principal\": {\n        \"Service\": [\"ec2.amazonaws.com\",\"ecs.amazonaws.com\"]\n      },\n      \"Effect\": \"Allow\",\n      \"Sid\": \"\"\n    }\n  ]\n}\n"
      create_date:           "<computed>"
      force_detach_policies: "false"
      name:                  "abcd"
      path:                  "/"
      unique_id:             "<computed>"
```

refer:

[terraform interpolation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html)

> jsonencode(item) - Returns a JSON-encoded representation of the given item, which may be a string, list of strings, or map from string to string. **Note that if the item is a string, the return value includes the double quotes**.

The reason I can't directly use vars with `"${var.iam_action}"`in `template_file` is explained here:

> vars - (Optional) Variables for interpolation within the template. Note that variables must all be primitives. **Direct references to lists or maps will cause a validation error**.

Comment: ```assume_role_policy:    "" => "{\n  \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\n  \"Statement\": [\n    {\n      \"Action\": \"sts:AssumeRole\",\n      \"Principal\": {\n        \"Service\": \"${var.actionl}\"\n      },\n      \"Effect\": \"Allow\",\n      \"Sid\": \"\"\n    }\n  ]\n}\n"
  create_date:           "" => "<computed>"``` Error: * aws_iam_role.s3_role: Error creating IAM Role s3_sysops_role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy: "SERVICE":"${var.iam_action}"

Comment: its rendering as ${foo} but its not rendering  foo =["a","b","c"]

Comment: @user60679 I fix and update the answer, should be fine now.

Comment: JSON is not a valid json

Comment: Error:  "assume_role_policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'e' after object key:value pair @BMW

Comment: Did you use my solution with seperate json policy file, or not? Seems you try to directly use `jsonencode` in the resource's statement.

Comment: I did use separate JSON file

Comment: Which terraform you are running? I test with `v0.10.0`